# Regular Expression match day

Tags: c#, regex, date, expression

I'm learning about Regex in C#, I've written the codes to check a valid day but Regex.Match is always false.

```
var pat = @"(today|tomorrow|yesterday)((?:\s*[+-]?\s*\d+\s*[dwym])*)"; // Can not change

Match match = Regex.Match(value, pat);
```

the match.Success is always false (value = 2017-07-07)

Which format can match with that pattern?

Comment: If your `value` is `2017-07-07`, your regex cannot match it.

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain more detail which format can match with that pattern

Comment: In fact the pattern is not even remotely close.

Comment: The pattern matches `today - 9 y, tomorrow + 1 w, etc.` ...

Comment: That regex matches strings like "today + 4 w - 6 w", "tomorrow-5d", "yesterday". To match a yyyy-mm-dd datestamp you could use `\b\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\b`.

Comment: Thanks @LukStorms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you actually trying to achieve? From the looks of it you are trying to match either some text (today/tomorrow/yesterday), or a date in a specific format?

Try this:

```
(today|tomorrow|yesterday|\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})
```

Try using a regular expression designer as well. I use Rad Software Regular Expression Designer 1.4.

Comment: Never trust a regex designer.

Comment: @revo why not? It's great for learning and you still have to type up your regex by hand... It's just a tool to help testing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I cannot change that pattern because it's system design, and I just write a function to check a day is valid.

Comment: @QuiNguyen Uhm, then try to parse it without using regex? F.e. [this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Thanks all, I got it.